# Adding image to the GDrive document header

Tags: image, api, google-drive-api

I've got web-application that works with google docs. App is uploading docs to GDrive with convertation and then i need to add image into converted document's header. How can i do this using GDrive API? I can't download full document or some converted formats, so i need to do this on google server. I am using SDK for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive API doesn't provide features to manipulate Google Docs files. What you can do is to modify the original file and upload again with conversion switched on. You can also use Google Apps Script. Please check out [Document.header-section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/header-section) for more details.